# DB2 connection without specifying username and password

Tags: java, database, db2

I have installed `DB2 Express C 9.7.4` edition.

I am establishing `DB2 Connection` using `JAVA language`.

But I have to still provide `user name and password of my windows Login` account for establishing connection...

Is it necessary to mention it ?

Is there any way out that can establish connection without specifying user name/password as during installation we have skipped the page.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible to set up a db to accept anonymous connections.  Why don't you set up a db account with the privileges it needs?  That's how it's usually done.

Comment: Please don't allow un-authenticated connections to your database.  You're just asking for somebody to go for the information inside...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an application runs on the same machine as the database server, DB2 will make the assumption that the userID that started the application has already been authenticated by the operating system – so no additional authentication is necessary.  This is referred to as *impicit authentication*.

So, without making changes to the default DB2 database configuration, you can do this if the following conditions are met:

1. The java application must be running on the same machine as the DB2 database
2. Your application must use a JDBC Type 2 connection (JDBC URL should look like `jdbc:db2:database` – not `jdbc://localhost:50000/database`).
3. The userID executing the Java application has authority to connect to the DB2 database, query the appropriate tables, etc.

It is possible to allow implicit authentication for applications running on machines other than the database server, but this requries setting up trusted contexts or opening a big security hole (changing the `AUTHENTICATION` database configuration parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The option that you mention in the screenshot is just to indicate the way the instance and other services are started. It does not mean the authentication mechanism used in DB2.

In order to permit an unknown user to connect to the database, you have to grant "connection" to public group. By doing this, any user could connect to the database, and it is not necessary to give the credentials.

```
db2 GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO PUBLIC
```

For more information:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050616.html

Comment: note that granting access to the general public is usually a _really bad idea_, as this more easily leads to data breaches.  If you run a business you could be considered in violation of PCI (or local equivalent).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Authentication (validating a user is who she says she is) has nothing to do with authorization (whether a user has the right to connect to a database, query from a table, etc.).  The OP is asking about how to use implicit authentication with a java app.