# Setup local db2 server for password less access from python

Tags: python, db2, odbc

I want to setup a local `db2` database to allow local users to connect without using password (specifically via `python`).

I can connect to the database from cli w/o password as `db2 connect to <DATABASE>`.

However, when trying to connect from within python using official [ibm_db api](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/bg/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html) as 
`ibm_db.connect("database", "", "")`
throws the following error: 

`SQL 300082N Security processing failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION"). SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30082`

Based on the [documentation for authentication options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005435.html), I have set the following options:

```
AUTHENTICATION=CLIENT
TRUST_CLNTAUTH=CLIENT
TRUST_ALLCLNTS=YES
```

however, I am still getting the same error.

P.S. #1: *I am not concerned about user authentication as they have already been authenticated before been allowed to log in to the server.*

P.S. #2: A similar question has already been asked at [DB2 connection without specifying username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291677/db2-connection-without-specifying-username-and-password). However, I need to connect via python and even with the setting 1 and 3 prescribed in the accepted answer, the connection fails.

P.S. #3: Possibly relevant link - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237107

Comment: CLIENT is not supported by the CLI driver which is used by the Python SDK: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic19.html#sql30082n

Comment: What are your real requirements? You could use a different authentication model and still achieve a kind of password-less connection.

Comment: I don't have python configured at hand, but can you try the following? `ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=database;Instance=my_db2_instance_name;PROTOCOL=IPC;", "", "")`

Comment: The passwordless connection from python to local database works for me with the PROTOCOL=IPC. Works with both python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 with Db2 v11.1 on linux. No need to change AUTHENTICATION or other dbm cfg settings.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! the `IPC` protocol does work. Is there a way, `TCPIP` protocol can also work - the corresponding sa library `ibm_db_sa` uses that. o.w.  if one of you can add this as an answer, I will accept it.

@data_henrik my requirement was to able to connect to db2 from within python w/o providing any password.

Comment: @goofd That is not really a good requirement. Have you heard of trusted contexts and trusted connections? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0050514.html